# Using self made libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to make my own libraries that I can use in future *projects*. My issue is that the tutorials I find and understand all tell me to create my new *project* in the solution that my library resides in. This is what I find weird.

My knowledge tells me that a library is supposed to house reusable code and will be used with different projects. Having to force my project to the same solution as my library to use it seems odd and how would it then work if I had to use two different libraries that I have made? I feel like I have missed something obvious.

After searching I have stumbled across something called external libraries, but the only useful thing I understood from this is that *"this might be the key*".

**My question is**: How can I create multiple libraries that I can use one or more of in different projects? Or have I misunderstood something crucial and what I am looking for is entirely different? If so, how and where should I create one or more files with reusable code meant to be used across different projects?

This might seem like a no-brainer type of question and I agree! But my googling skills are not up to par to find a solution. Thank you and sorry for using your time.

I am using Visual Studio 2012.
Example of tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx

Comment: have you used any external libraries before, for instance `boost`?

Comment: Although the example suggests you to add the project to already available solution, I assume, they did it for simplicity. You can do the same thing in a separate solution.

Comment: Have a look into the wonderful world of NuGet: you can wrap your libraries up into a neat little package and then add it to any number of projects.

Comment: Does NuGet work on C++ projects?

Comment: Either I did something horribly wrong or you can not do the same thing in a separate solution as SergeyA recommended. I will have to take a better look at NuGet thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a C++ Win32 Console App project there is an option on the new project wizard to create a library.

Create your libraries in a single solution and add a post build step to copy them to a "central folder".
In you code that uses the libraries add an include path to your "Central folder"
Add a reference to the library in the project properties, like you would if you were including a windows or boost library.

Comment: You might want to be very careful with post-build steps - e.g. if you don't have thorough test coverage as part of the build it will "deploy" something just because it compiles and links